# Difference between Powershell's '.replace' and '-replace' commands

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have an xml meta data file whose header I need to change. The header looks like this:

```
<BuildEntry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="blablaName" Version="r26" Author="blablaAuthor" Website="blablaWebsite">
```

The idea is to run a Get-Content replace on this file and set the version to the current build version for the project. In above case, version is r26. It can be rXX where X is any number.

I need it to change to r01 or r67 where 01 and 67 are the latest project build numbers.

My Powershell build script looks like this but does not work:

```
$prevVerionHeader = 'Version="((r)\d*)" Author='
$newVerionHeader = 'Version="r'+$number+'" Author='
Write-Host $prevVerionHeader
Write-Host $newVerionHeader

(Get-Content $SBmetaDataPath).replace($prevVerionHeader,$newVerionHeader) | Out-File $SBmetaDataPath
```

$SBmetaDataPath is the full path to the file and $number is the latest build number.

If I use the following then replace happens perfectly:

```
$prevVerionHeader = 'Version="r26" Author='
```

What I need is a regex pattern that will match against Version="rXX". I realize having rXX between double quotes may be causing problems here.

Please help. I do have some experience with Powershell but it is very intimidating and confusing. Also it's too late to change my automated build file to something other than Powershell.

Solution in case someone comes by here:

```
(Get-Content $SBmetaDataPath) -replace($prevVerionHeader,$newVerionHeader) | Out-File $SBmetaDataPath
```

As explained:
String.Replace() does regular string substitution, -replace is a regex operator – Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: You are looking for the `-replace` operator, not a `.replace()` function. Is there a reason for you not modifying your **XML** file as... you know, **XML**? Regex parsing of markup languages usually turn into a nightmare

Comment: Oh my dear God! That did it. `-replace` is the way to go, I used `.replace` before and it worked then but wasn't not working for this particular edit. Anyway thank you soo much! Also since you asked i need to edit the XML so I can deploy the code with the XML file. Another tool is then supposed to read the XML. Having the editing process automated means I need only run the powershell script and never worry about correcting the XML's details. Thanks a tonne!

Comment: `String.Replace()` does regular string substitution, `-replace` is a regex operator

Comment: Ohhh! That explains it! How do i give you reputation? I need to give you reputation!

Comment: Can you just answer it so I can give you rep! :) Correct code: `(Get-Content $SBmetaDataPath) -replace($prevVerionHeader,$newVerionHeader) | Out-File $SBmetaDataPath`